# Regarding ASCII values

Tags: ascii

If we have to store 'A' in memory than ASCII value of A is 65. 65 will converted to binary 01000001 then it will be stored. So my question is when we store integers, are they also converted according to their ASCII value then in binary.
and if not then why do we have ASCII values for numbers

Comment: We don't have ASCII values for numbers, we have ASCII values for digits.

Comment: There are only ASCII values for the individual digits.  You can verify for yourself when you look [at an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Keep in mind that, more often than not, you are using a character set other than ASCII, such [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter) or [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). But you already knew that, right? 

Answer (score 0):

Integers are stored in memory as 32 bit ints. If an int doesn't fill all 32 bits 0's are used. There is no need to convert to ASCII unless you are explicitly trying to find the ASCII value of a specific integer.

Try [this](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/embed/chap3/chap3.htm#BINARY) link for more info on integer representation.